# iOS app localization and build for one language

Tags: ios, localization

I would like to relase two versions of the same appliaction in different languages. (to be clear - I don't want to release just one app with option to change language but two apps, each one in different language).

The process of app localizationing is described for instance in this tutorial http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-tutorial-localization-apps/ but it creates one app with option to change languages.

My question is - is it possible following this method to build (archive) an application in just one language, and then the second one in another?

If not please advise me what would be the best method to do so?

Comment: Create two apps, each with a different default language?

Comment: Two apps? And what about the updates? Write the same things twice? Not a good idea imo.

Comment: Perhaps that's why Apple chose the approach they did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two exactly the same but separate applications imho - not the best choice!
it means two source code projects, right, with localized separate `xibs`, `stories` etc?!

You know why?! Simply because it's difficult to support.

If you need to fix something -> welcome to fix in both projects etc...

You should follow the tutorial and create localized application for two different languages.
I'm assuming to submit both versions to `appStore` you need to:
When submitting:

- set different languages as a default
- replace bundle identifier smtl like
  `com.yourCompany.yourAppName_english/spanish`

so you can submit the same application but with different default language.
This is just theoretical... hope it helps

Comment: Yeah, I agree that creating two apps is not the best choice - hence my question. I like this approach. So it's possible to set default language of an application after localizing it? How can I do this?

Comment: I guess this is another question, hope there is similar answers

Answer (score 0):

One Language App = No Localization = No need to follow the tutorial 
(you just build the app with all NSString with one language)

Your Localized App support more than one language will need to follow the tutorial